# Cropping an image in android without using intents

Tags: android

Currently I am using default android camera intent to crop an image. But this is not working properly in some of the devices. In pure android devices, the crop is not getting called or the return data is null. Is there any other method to achieve the same.

Currently I use following code to start crop,

```
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
cropIntent.setType("image/*");
if(picUri != null) {
    cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
}
String tmpName = imageDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "img.jpg";
File tmpFile = new File(tmpName);
if (tmpFile.exists()) {
    tmpFile.delete();
}
Uri tmpUri = Uri.fromFile(tmpFile);
cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 16);
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 9);
cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 320);
cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 180);
cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tmpUri);
startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
```

Comment: i am done it with intents but work on every device

Comment: In few devices the above code will not work especially the ones with pure android. It is always safe to avoid using camera intent to crop an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/edmodo/cropper) library. This supports cropping of images without using Camera crop intent. It also supports many other features like rotate etc. It is easy to implement

The [sample](https://github.com/edmodo/cropper/tree/master/CropperSample) provided is also well written.

Comment: The link is not valid anymore, please give us updated link.

Answer (score -1):

If the image can be loaded into memory, you can use [BitmapFactory.decodeFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String%29) to load to Bitmap, and do the crop on the Bitmap with [createBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29). Be careful doing this with arbitrary images because the decode will crash if it runs out of memory to load the image.

Comment: How can we do a crop on desired section of the image using this method? The cropper library mentioned above have in built feature which shows the selection area.

Comment: The linked method takes top left corner and width and height as arguments. There are many other variants of createBitmap which take different arguments for different operations.This doesn't provide any UI, so you'll need to work out the sizes yourself or use a library.